# Selecting checkboxlist checked items

Tags: c#, checkboxlist

I have tried looking round for a solution to my problem but have failed to find one as it seems every one is a step or two ahead of my problem.

I am trying to select an item from it being checked from a checkboxlist rather than selecting an item from it being selected.

What I intend to do from knowing that is to make the resulting event that would fire off, after a button is clicked and the checked options are checked, to show text in a label off the checked items.

The program, based off the decorator pattern, would allow the user to choose from a set of 3/4 checkable options of which when a button is pressed will show text relating to those items in a label on the end of the base text. At the moment, all I have managed is to get it to do so on the selected item one at a time only similar to the first example.

For example, when an option called Monitor is checked it would show in the label:

You're getting a Computer and a monitor.

If there are multiple checked items such as Monitor and Keyboard then it would say:

You're getting a Computer and a monitor and a keyboard.

Comment: Just want to clarify, you want to trigger the list based on a checkbox tick event?

Comment: Yes, windows forms application. The list of options is generated on the application starting, user presses a button of which the event described, text appearing in label as per the option checked, is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change the `Label.Text` property of the target `Label` when the `ItemCheck` event of the `CheckedListBox` is fired based on the new checked item value.

**Example**

Assuming that you have a `Label` of name `label1`, a `CheckedListBox` of name `checkedListBox1` and a `Form` of name `Form1`, the following may apply

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = "You are getting "; //Change the Text property of label1 to "You are getting "
        checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(checkedListBox1_ItemCheck); //Link the ItemCheck event of checkedListBox1 to checkedListBox1_ItemCheck; not required as long as you link the event through the designer
    }
    private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked && e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Unchecked) //Continue if the new CheckState value of the item is changing to Checked
        {
            label1.Text += "a " + checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString() + ", "; //Append ("a " + the item's value + ", ") to the label1 Text property
        }
        else if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked && e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Checked) //Continue if the new CheckState value of the item is changing to Unchecked
        {
            label1.Text = label1.Text.Replace("a " + checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString() + ", ", ""); //Replace ("a " + the item's value + ", ") with an empty string and assign this value to the label1 Text property
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>**Sample Input**</sup>

```
[x] Monitor
[x] Keyboard
[ ] Mouse
[x] Computer
```

<sup>**Sample Output**</sup>

```
You are getting a Monitor, a Keyboard, a Computer,
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Second line of that code has given me 5 errors:

1. 'Decorator_Pattern.Form1.checkedListBox1' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'. 
2. 'Decorator_Pattern.Form1.checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object, System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'. 
3. Identifier expected (for the last bracket).
4. Invalid token '+=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration. 
5. Method must have a return type (for 'ItemCheckEventHandler')

Comment: @SergioJanuario You should do this under `public Form1()` after `InitializeComponent();`. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, works now. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @SergioJanuario I'm glad I could help. [Please notice that you may mark a post as an answer to indicate that you have already solved the problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png). Have a nice day :)

Comment: I'm going to play around with it for a while first to make sure it is what I was looking for before I do anything else. It works fine but I'm not sure it is what I'm looking for as it seems to be circumventing the way the decorator pattern works which is what I'm trying to base this appliciation off and keep too. Been up all night, not sure how much longer I'll be able to stay up to play around with it (my reason if I don't reply to a comment anytime soon).

Comment: @SergioJanuario I hope you get your problem resolved as soon as possible. Please let me know if I can do anything further :)

Comment: Is there any way where instead of the ToString being used to get the text, another variable could be used instead? I ask because I use one through out my code called "description" which holds/returns all the required text to be shown in the label which if used instead of ToString would be keeping to the decorator pattern more  closely in my opinion as ToString could be used without the use of the decorator pattern structure while my "description" could not.

Comment: @SergioJanuario Not really sure what do you mean, but we've used `ToString()` to convert the `object` to a `string`. You may surely do something like `string myString = checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();` to have a string of name `myString` as the item value. Have a nice day :)

Comment: It still uses the ToString values, what I would like to do is to be able to set which text comes out of each option which can be selected through a different value to the what is being stored in the ToString value. The code I'm using which is what I have attempted to use to do so is as follows: `Computer computer = new Computer();
        string myString = checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();
        myString = computer.description();`

Comment: Description returns a different set of text to that of what the ToString of each option has been set to of which is what I would like to be using instead if that is at all possible.

Comment: @SergioJanuario It's not clear what you are trying to do. Please do not hesitate to [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which describes your problem more clearly. Happy Holidays! :)